# Php variable turning into echo in if statement

Tags: php, database, laravel-blade

Im trying to do an if statement to only display data with the passed ID. The value itself works as I can display it inside a h1 for example. And the if statements also work as if I replace $id with a hard coded value i.e. 2 this also works. But when using both together I get the error "syntax error, unexpected token "<" ". Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

```
 @foreach ($placements as $placement)
    @foreach($placement->dates as $date)
    @if ($placement->id == {{$id}})
    <h2> {{ $placement->subject->subject }}</h2>
            <h2> {{ $placement->keystage->age_group }}</h2>
            <h2> {{ $placement->start_time }}</h2>
            <h2> {{ $placement->end_time }}</h2>
            <h2> {{ $date->date }}</h2>  
    @endif                              

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

[image]

Comment: When you're inside the blade directive, you don't need the double braces. So `@if ($placement->id == {{$id}})` should be `@if ($placement->id == $id)`

Comment: Thanks thought it would be something simple like that :)